Create a RecursivePartializer
I have the following typescript code
type Bar = {
    foo: string;
    prop: number;
    baz: {
        value: string;
        check: boolean;
    }
}

I want to create a mapped type such that
type PartiallyBar = MyRecursivePartializer<Bar, "foo"|"baz.check">
yields this type as a result
type PartiallBar = {
    foo?: string; //this was made into an optional 
    prop: number;
    baz: {
        value: string;
        check: boolean; //this was made into an optional 
    }
}

and the following
type PartiallyBar2 = MyRecursivePartializer<Bar, "foo"|"baz">
should yield
type PartiallBar2 = {
    foo?: string; //this was made into an optional 
    prop: number;
    baz?: {  //the property was made optional and its sub properties too (recursively)
        value?: string;
        check?: boolean;
    }
}

The whole thing should (in theory) work for any nested path(s) and if path(s) conflict then the broader should take precedence
Alternatively: there is a library that does that already.
Thx

You can make a recursive type like so:
type RecursivePartializer<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends {} ? RecursivePartializer<T[P]> : T[P];
}

type Test = RecursivePartializer<Bar>

const test: Test = {
  baz: {
    value: "optional"
  }
}

Typescript playground
If you want the type definition to be expanded, when hovered on with intellisense. Check this out

Sorry, this does not want I want. This makes everything partial. It should make just those things partial that have been explictly named

After a day of intense hacking I found a solution to define a recursive optional Type where I can reach into a deeply nested type to switch any (nested) property into an optional property.
//need to use Pick2 instead of Pick because Pick only works with keyof T
type Pick2<T, Path extends string> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends Path
    ? T[K]
    : never;
};

//Helper to remove never properties which will be generated by Pick2
//as it works with strings and not the keyof operator
type RemoveNeverProperties<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
};

//we first omit the properties that are to be optional & then we pick those
//remove any never props and make the result Partial
//at last we join the remainder with the newly partial properties
type Optional2<T extends object, K extends string> =
    Omit<T, K> & Partial<RemoveNeverProperties<Pick2<T, K>>>;

//Helper to check if a property needs to be handled recursevely
//and Helper that cuts the prefix for the next nesting level
type ShiftPath<Key extends PropertyKey, Path extends PropertyKey> =
    Path extends `${Extract<Key, string>}.${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never;

//Putting everything together
export type DeepRecursiveOptional<T, Path extends string> = 
    //make the defined props optional if they match on this nesting level
    Optional2<{
        //iterate thru each prop
        [K in keyof T]:
            //check if a "path" points into the next nesting level
            ShiftPath<K, Path> extends never
            //if not return the property without any change
            ? T[K]
            //else recursively apply optionality
            : DeepRecursiveOptional<T[K], ShiftPath<K, Path>>;
    }, Path>;

type A = {
    prop_a: string
    prop_b: string
    prop_c: {
        prop_d: boolean
        prop_e: number
        prop_f: {
            prop_g: Date
            prop_h: string
        }
    }
}

type B = DeepRecursiveOptional<A, "prop_a" | "prop_c.prop_d" | "prop_c.prop_f.prop_g">

const b: B = {
    //prop_a: "test",
    prop_b: "test",
    prop_c: {
        //prop_d: true,
        prop_e: 1,
        prop_f: {
            //prop_g: new Date(),
            prop_h: "test"
        }
    }
}

This solution is not as typesafe as one would wish for as I am operating with strings that define paths instead of using the keyof operator. Otoh it seems to me a rather insignificant drawback. If one defines a path into a (nested) property that does not exist due to a typo (let say "footbar" vs "foobar" ´) then the only thing that happens is that at the usage site the property will be still required instead of optional and the compiler will tell that
